# Jenkins ArchiveArtifacts missing link

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my scripted pipeline I want to store the test result and the build artifact. I am using *archiveArtifacts* step twice:

- first with a path to test results
- second with a path to the application

The problem I have is that on Jenkins job page there are only links to the test reports, there is no link available to download an application which was archived. I monitored the logs and seems that application is archived correctly but the link is not shown. What could be the reason for a missing link?

Comment: Do they appear, when you only archive the build artifacts and no test results?

Comment: When I archive just the build (tests result archive is skipped) then I can see the link.

Comment: I fixed it by calling archiveArtifacts once but with all three artifacts (one build, two test reports). In that case, all is fine. However, it should be mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Did you open an issue or pull request?

Comment: Not yet - I will do it today